# Are there classic dungeons?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I understand Breath of the Wild is not intended as a "classic" Zelda game, and I love this and I really like the game, but I just need to know: does the game have classic "vast" dungeons (i.e. huge mazes) or they're just shrines and mini-dungeons?

To elaborate (spoiler alert):

> I'm playing Breath of the Wild following the storyline and I've just completed Vah Ruta, which was the first dungeon-like quest I have encountered so far: it has self-contained location, a dedicated map and a final boss… but it's a four-room dungeon with just a couple of foes, which in my opinion does not classify it as a "classic" Zelda dungeon.

Comment: As far as the game has led me to believe there aren't any.  Although I haven't beat the game and everything it has to offer so I can't confirm that.

Comment: I have done one secret boss and there is no dungeon associated with this secret boss whatsoever. So it is safe to assume those area will be the most dungeon-like you will find in-game.

Comment: I think you're looking for Tears of the Kingdom, not Breath of the Wild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to a dungeon would be the Divine Beast "dungeons."

They have puzzle aspects found in traditional Zelda games, but they themselves are very short (comparatively) and yet fundamentally different from every other game in the series.

Answer (score 1):

The only other real "dungeon" is Hyrule Castle, which gets it's own minimap just like the Divine Beasts.